# schtask highest privileges without specifying user

Tags: devops, windows-task-scheduler

I exported one scheduled job I created. And it should be possible to import that task to other computers using cmd/powershell.

Is there a way to tell schtask that it should use current user that is logged on and use the highest privileges to execute this job?

May help:
All computer are in the same local network and sem system group.
Console where schtask import xml is executed already has admin rights.

```
schtask \create \tn <myService> \xml <my xml path>
```

If schtask can somehow prompt for which user to use it would be ok. Even if it will ask for a password.

But I don't want to write user password into cmd as argument (i don't see that option safe for my situation)

Perfect would be to just automatically select the current user that is logged on.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified to run the script as "User" and it works on all computer. If someone can explain what this User means would be nice